# java.lang.NullPointerException on custom android camera

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I am making a custom camera in android studio. If I exit the app, it crashes upon returning to it. I know the problem lies within the activity lifecycle and the logcat points out the line where I have `mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder)' in the cameraPreview.java file. I have seen other posts similar to this but I'm still not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

homePage.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.hardware.Camera;

public class homePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION = 123;
    private static final String TAG = "homePage";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;

    private boolean cameraPermission() {
        int CameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        List<String> cameraPermissionNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (CameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            cameraPermissionNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (!cameraPermissionNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    cameraPermissionNeeded.toArray(new String[cameraPermissionNeeded.size()]),
                    CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch(requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Certain permissions needed to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasCamera() {

        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
            return true;
        }else {

            AlertDialog camAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(homePage.this).create();
            camAlert.setTitle("Alert");
            camAlert.setMessage("there is no usable camera");
            camAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            camAlert.show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static android.hardware.Camera getCameraInstance() {
        android.hardware.Camera c = null;

        try {
            c = android.hardware.Camera.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d(TAG, "camera in use or does not exist");
        }
        return c;
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        cameraPermission();
        hasCamera();

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hasCamera();
        mCamera.stopPreview();

        if (this.mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseCamera();

    }
}
```

cameraPreview.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.io.IOException;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
//==================logcat points out this line===================

            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);

//================================================================
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mSurfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //blank
        }
    }
}
```

logcat

```
08-09 11:48:17.192 8075-8075/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-09 11:48:17.223 8075-8082/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-09 11:48:17.224 8075-8082/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-09 11:48:17.224 8075-8082/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-09 11:48:17.319 8075-8075/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/hernanrazo.camera-1/lib/arm64
08-09 11:48:17.331 8075-8075/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-09 11:48:17.394 8075-8075/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-09 11:48:17.544 8075-8128/? I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 6818200, Idb2b4cb785
                                         Build Date                       : 11/17/16
                                         OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.04
                                         Local Branch                     : N25
                                         Remote Branch                    : 
                                         Remote Branch                    : 
                                         Reconstruct Branch               : 
08-09 11:48:17.565 8075-8128/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-09 11:48:17.565 8075-8128/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-09 11:48:24.832 8075-8075/hernanrazo.camera W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
08-09 11:48:24.832 8075-8075/hernanrazo.camera W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
08-09 11:48:28.527 8075-8075/hernanrazo.camera I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-09 11:48:28.914 8075-8075/hernanrazo.camera W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
08-09 11:48:43.705 8075-8075/hernanrazo.camera D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-09 11:48:43.706 8075-8075/hernanrazo.camera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: hernanrazo.camera, PID: 8075
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at hernanrazo.camera.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:36)
                                                                     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:618)
                                                                     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:247)
                                                                     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:10357)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1290)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1290)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1290)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1290)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1290)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1290)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1290)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1544)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6338)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is the function

> surfaceDestroyed()

because this method  call to

> releaseCamera()

And in that method the camera variable is setting null, please check in wich moment is executed surfaceDestroyed() function.

Comment: Should I just call 'mCamera.release();' instead of 'releaseCamera();' ?

Comment: Try removing mCamera = null in releaseCamera() function.

Comment: Doing this removes the nullPointerException error but the logcat now tells me that the camera is being used after Camera.release() was called

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251691/camera-is-being-used-after-camera-release-was-called